# Creating a Table(array) of Records

Tags: python, arrays, function, loops

If I wanted to store records from two files into a table (an array of records), could I use a format similar to the below code, and just put both file names in def function like def readTable(log1,log2): and then use the same code for both log1 and log2 allowing it to make a table1 and a table2?

```
def readTable(fileName):
    s = Scanner(fileName)
    table = []
    record = readRecord(s)
    while (record != ""):
        table.append(record)
        record = readRecord(s)
    s.close()            
    return table
```

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Answer (score 1):

Just use *args, and get a list of records?

```
def readTable(*args):
    tables = []
    for filename in args:
        s = Scanner(fileName)
        table = []
        record = readRecord(s)
        while (record != ""):
            table.append(record)
            record = readRecord(s)
        s.close()
        tables.append(table)
    return tables
```

This way, you can pass log1, log2, log3 (any number of logs you like and get back a list of tables for each

Comment: So for s = Scanner (fileName) can I just sub in something like, log1 or log2?

Comment: if you just call `readTable(log1, log2)` you'll get back `[[table1],[table2]]`

Answer (score 0):

Since `readTable` returns a list, if you want to concatenate the records from 2 logs, use the `+` operator.

```
readTable(log1) + readTable(log2)
```

Comment: so would I use the above code for log1 and log2 that i posted then at the end call the function that you provided?